# The meaning of ''in the middle of nowhere''

Tags: meaning, idiom-meaning

Please tell me the meaning of this phrase:'In the middle of nowhere'.

I've found its meaning in Cambridge dictionary and The free dictionary by Farlex, but still, I can't understand.

Comment: (in) the middle of nowhere
- (informal disapproving)
 
*far away from any towns and cities and where few people live:* 
“He lives in a tiny house in the middle of nowhere.” Cambridge

Comment: It could be anywhere, but you look in all directions and you don't see anything you recognize.  Out in the desert is probably the first thing that comes to mind, but it could be the prairie, in a forest, or in downtown New York City, if that is unfamiliar to you.

Comment: @HotLicks  Thanks a million. I got it!

Comment: @Hachi Thank you very much! <3

Comment: It is irony. You are not just isolated, but in *isolation central*. Not just nowhere, but in the most important part of nowhere - the middle.

Comment: "He's a nobody" means that he's not worthy of being considered, not that he doesn't actually exist. Similarly, in this expression (and rarely elsewhere) 'nowhere' conjures up the image of 'lands left blank on maps', featureless, nothing worth looking at or digging for; usually far from civilisation. 'In the middle of nowhere' is as as off-grid it gets. The _back of beyond_.

Comment: Thanks to @EdwinAshworth now I know more about it!

Comment: @HotLicks Downtown New York would certainly not be described as "the middle of nowhere", whether you're familiar with the city or not. On the other hand, if you're in a remote desert that you've visited many times, you can still be in "the middle of nowhere", even though you know the location very well. Middle of nowhere-ness has to do with the remoteness, featurelessness, and insignificance of a place, not how familiar you are with it. Someplace doesn't become "the middle of nowhere" just because it's your first time there.

Comment: @NuclearWang - You're not from Waldorf Minnesota.  You're in NYC and call a friend to come and get you because you're lost.  He asks where you are, and you say "The middle of nowhere".

Comment: @HotLicks And he'd say "look for a street sign, they're on every corner". It might apply if you're in some odd corner of a borough, far from anything useful, but again that requires a sense of remoteness. To say you're in the middle of nowhere implies a lack of other meaningful descriptors. If you're on 42nd and 5th, you're at a bustling place with a well-defined, meaningful, and recognizable way to express the location. You might say you don't know where you are, but to say that it's the middle of nowhere defies the definition, which is a "remote or isolated place".

Comment: @NuclearWang - It's a metaphor!